# pass to kendoListView Template param as ko.computed

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, kendo-ui

I need computed template for listView.

It mean that I have observable field (calld view).
when view=='full'- I need one template.
When view id changed to be 'prtial' - I need the template to changed at real-time.

so, I would want to write:

```
 currentListView.kendoListView({
          dataSource: vm.dataSource,
          template: kendo.template(ko.computed(function(){return view()=='full'?firstTemplate:secondTemplate;})),
         //code continue
```

But it doesn't work...

Can you tell me exactly how to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

I would first point you to the KO documentation, it's really good on computed fields: [KO Computed](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html)

Try this, you are missing a ", this" in your code.  I don't have context on what view() is, so I assume it's an observable or pure JS function defined outside of the snippet you provided.

```
 currentListView.kendoListView({
          dataSource: vm.dataSource,
          template: kendo.template(
                     ko.computed(function(){
                                return view() === 'full' ? firstTemplate : secondTemplate; 
                     }, this)),
     //code continue
```